# Wrap <ul> around every 6 <li> with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to use jQuery to wrap `<ul class="main-list">` around each 6 of it's first children `<li>`'s. What's the best way to accomplish this with jQuery?

Here's the jQuery I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lis = $(".main-list li");
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=6) {
      lis.slice(i, i+6)
         .wrapAll("<ul class='list_unstyled'></ul>");
    }
});
```

Here's the original code (ExpressionEngine):

```
<ul class="list-unstyled main-list">
    {exp:channel:category_archive channel="speakers" style="linear" backspace="7"}
        <li>
            {categories}
                <a href="#">{category_name}</a>
            {/categories} 
            {entry_titles}  
            <ul class="list-unstyled"> 
                <li><a href="{path='site/speaker'}">{title}</a></li>
            </ul>  
            {/entry_titles}     
        </li>   
    {/exp:channel:category_archive}     
</ul>
```

Here's the code that's currently being outputted with jquery above:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled main-list">
    <ul class="list_unstyled">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list_unstyled">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Here's the desired result after implementing jQuery:

```
<ul class="list_unstyled">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list_unstyled">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please include your jQuery code and original HTML so we can help to troubleshoot.

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I actually tried a few pieces of jQuery code, but with no luck so didn't post with my questions. Don't' think it would be relevant.

Comment: Fair enough. It seems to me that it will be helpful to see what you've already tried and what specifically went wrong. I find that this procedure facilitates learning (for both current and future readers) more than just generating code according to a specification.

Comment: @ Sergey Denisov, yes it's similar, and I've come across this post, but it's not quite the same thing.

Comment: @showdev, pasted my jQuery above and modified my question a bit. Please keep me posted. Thank you!

Comment: eh? you change it.. now it doesn't make sense.. do you want to wrap each 6 li's with a .main-list? or do you want to remove the  .main-list?

Comment: @Keith I did simplify code a bit just to make more understandable. Really, I'm trying to turn the outputted code above into the desired result above. Let me know if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jquery function already does what you wanted, which is to group them by 6, so you just need to remove the .main-list wrapping your list. all you need to do is unwrap after the loop.

```
$('.main-list>ul').unwrap();
```

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lis = $(".main-list li");
    for(var i = 0; i < lis.length; i+=6) {
      lis.slice(i, i+6)
         .wrapAll("<ul class='list_unstyled'></ul>");
    }

    $('.main-list>ul').unwrap();

});
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith A, that did the trick with one minor adjustment: `var lis = $(".main-list > li");`

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this:

```js
function wrapLi( parent ){
    var numChildren = $( parent ).children( 'li' ).length,
        wrappers = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < numChildren / 6; i++ ){
        wrappers[i] = $( '<ul class="main-list"></ul>' );

        // the meat and potatoes... select the first six elements of the matched set
        // check out http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
        wrappers[i].append( $( parent ).children( 'li:lt(6)' ) );
    }

    return wrappers; // the array of <ul> that you can put wherever you want
}

var stuff = wrapLi(  $( '.main-list' ) );

$( 'body' ).append( stuff );
```

Also here is a fiddle where you can mess with it.
http://jsfiddle.net/nfw0kpxt/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pj64sgko/)

Very easily solved.

```
var firstUl = $("<ul>");
var secondUl = $("<ul>");
var size = $(".main-list li").size();
var elements = $(".main-list li");
size--;

for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    firstUl.append(elements[i]);
}

secondUl.append(elements[size++]);

$(".result").append(firstUl);
$(".result").append(secondUl);
```

Comment: wtf, you changed the question totally